# Dojo 1.8: Seems that there's no way to load dojo file into contentpane, is it?

Tags: dojo

Hi I have tried every ways and means to load dojo page into ContentPane.
It seems That I am not able to do that. Correct me if I am wrong.

Looks like the only solution is through the creation and destroy of any widget while running

Clement

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The dojo docs for **dojox**/layout/ContentPane (which allows references to script files)  mentions your issue:

> NOTE that dojo.require in script in the fetched file isn't recommended Many widgets need to be required at page load to work properly
>   @see http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.8/dojox/layout/ContentPane

It looks like you just need to require these files in the parent widget.